# Excel Conditional Formatting Formula Changes After I Apply The Rule

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, formula

Every time I make a new conditional formatting rule it changes and breaks. This happens before I click apply, but after I have created the rule. If I apply the rule it, naturally, applies completely incorrectly, but I don't have any idea what the formula is checking. If I then edit the text of the formula after applying it, it will then work and stay the way I have written it.

It seems to be just adding a long string of numbers at the end of my formula location.
In the images below I am adding a new formula:

> =$J1="N"

but after hitting ok it changes to this:

> =$J1048564="N"

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: How my formulas should look (these are ones I've already fixed)]

[image: Entering a new formula]

[image: What the formula changes to after I hit ok]

[image: How the formula applies if I hit ok with the numbers]

[image: After fixing the formula working correctly (also changed the order of the formulas and added a stop if true so it looks a little different]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The row number does not have a $ sign, so it is relative. It is relative to the cell that was the **active cell** when the format **was defined**.

If you apply a format to A1:A1000, but the currently active cell is in row 500, then a relative reference to $A1 in the formula will be interpreted as "The cell 499 rows above the current cell". When that format is applied, then Excel will try to find that position for each row. In row 1, it cannot go 499 cells above, so it starts over at the last cell of the sheet and goes 499 up from there.

Of course you don't want all that.

So, when you define a conditional format that applies to many rows, make sure that the currently active cell is at the top left of the selected range, so any relative cell references will be applied relative to that cell position.

You may want to remove your CF completely and start over.

Comment: Thank you very much! I figured it had to be something minor, but didn't realize when you select a range for conditional formatting it wouldn't just assume the active cell to apply the formula would be the top left. 

Working fine now (: